# Can you plot streamlines on Robinson projections?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plot streamlines on a global map with the Robinson projection, but basemap doesn't seem to like the projected co-ordinates. Of course, it works fine for a plain old cylindrical projection, which is regular in the x direction.

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

u = np.ones((21,21)) 
v = np.ones((21,21))
lats = np.arange(-90,91,9)
lons = np.arange(-180,181,18)
x,y = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

# It works for Cylindrical
mp = Basemap(projection='cyl')
xx,yy = mp(x,y)
mp.streamplot(xx,yy,u,v)
mp.drawcoastlines()
plt.show()

# But not Robinson
mp = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0)
xx, yy = mp(x, y) 
mp.streamplot(xx,yy,u,v)
mp.drawcoastlines()
plt.show()
```

It complains about the x co-ordinates, raising:

```
ValueError: The rows of 'x' must be equal
```

So is it possible to plot streamlines on Robinson projections?

Answer (score 2):

With the command `xx,yy = mp(x,y)` a coordinate transformation according to the particular projection is applied to your lon and lats. For most projections this will result in a distorsion of the gird point such that rows of x are no longer equal, hence the error: `ValueError: The rows of 'x' must be equal`. To fix this you need to re-grid your data, e.g. like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

u = np.ones((21,21)) 
v = np.ones((21,21))
lats = np.arange(-90,91,9)
lons = np.arange(-180,181,18)
x,y = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

mp = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0)
xx, yy = mp(x, y) 

# generate a grid that is equally spaced in a plot with the current pojection
lons, lats, xxnew, yynew = mp.makegrid(21,21, returnxy=True)

# project the data onto the new grid
unew = plt.mlab.griddata(xx.flatten(), yy.flatten(),u.flatten(), xxnew, yynew ,interp='linear')
vnew = plt.mlab.griddata(xx.flatten(), yy.flatten(),v.flatten(), xxnew, yynew ,interp='linear')

mp.streamplot(xxnew,yynew,unew,vnew)
mp.drawcoastlines()
plt.show()
```